# How to convert Xen image to VirtualBox?

Tags: xen, virtualbox, conversion

I have some open-source Xen images (.img), that I want to convert to VirtualBox.

Both the methods I tried (convertfromraw or to .xva via xva.py then to ova via XenConvert) produce FATAL: Fatal: No bootable medium found!.

Any idea what the most reliable method is for performing this conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a Windows or Linux instance you are trying to migrate? Have you tried following instructions from here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows ? As far as I am concerned Xen .img files are simple block device files meaning you can treat them as physical hard drives.

Comment: Also, if it's Windows, you will have to run their MBR repair tool. Just boot your VM into Windows Installation CD and see if detects installation. Follow the steps to repair MBR.

Comment: CentOS 64-bit, so they should work out of box (but they don't).

Comment: Are your CentOS VMs fully or para virtualised?

Comment: Para-virtual VM's.

Comment: Which means your VMs don't have their own kernel and initrd images (these are provided by Xen Dom0) so even if you were to install grub on the instance's disk (.img file) your machine would not boot. VirtualBox only runs fully virtualised VMs.

Comment: I would suggest you try converting your images to use pygrub http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/PyGrub . During this process you will install grub on your instance and at that point VM should be able to boot from VirtualBox. Oh and dont forget to provide an initrd and the kernel images to your VMs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the VirtualBox command line utility - vboxmanage.

vboxmanage clonehd XEN_disk.img VIRTUALBOX_disk.vdi

or

vboxmanage internalcommands converthd XEN_disk.img VIRTUALBOX_disk.vdi

or

Cheat. Use clonezilla or any cloning method.

Boot to clonezilla on the xen virtual client and virtualbox client using a clonezilla iso. Clone from xen to virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the native converter provided by zen this can be downloaded from below URL

```
http://downloadns.citrix.com.edgesuite.net/4810/XenConvert_Install.exe?_ga=2.114409543.1143128890.1531322576-1077525422.1529510520
http://downloadns.citrix.com.edgesuite.net/4812/XenConvert_Install_x64.exe?_ga=2.114409543.1143128890.1531322576-1077525422.1529510520
```